# Trouble sharing folders with people outside our organization

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm having trouble setting up folder and file sharing with people outside our organization.

I am trying to share a subfolder, not the entire folder tree. I'm the primary admin for the organization.

Within the Sharepoint Admin center this is what I see: 
[image]

And this is what I'm seeing when I try to share a folder: 
[image]

On the previous screen, I set "share the link with" to "People you choose"

[image]

But you can see that I can't choose "Anyone" in the previous screen.

Comment: you should check the settings of the site itself under SP admin centre > active sites. those are the tenant level settings. also, make sure you blur those email addresses

Comment: That worked! Problem solved. Thank you

Comment: great. I will post it a an actual answer for posterity

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the site settings (SharePoint Admin Centre > Active Sites), in particular the guest settings there as they are likely blocking the sharing.

In your case, you probably need to set them to "new and existing guests".